# Silverlight - Basic Container for a bunch of elements

Tags: silverlight

I have 3 things that I'd like to wrap up in something so that I can call the container from code and not each thing individually.

I can see there is a `Canvas` container but isn't there something more generic that just serves as a package that I can call?

Here is my current code:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="Black" Width="420" Height="480" Opacity=".5"></Rectangle>
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,50,0,0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"></Rectangle>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Foreground="White" Text="Loading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,65,0,0"></TextBlock>
```

I wish I could do this:

```
<Container>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="Black" Width="420" Height="480" Opacity=".5"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,50,0,0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"></Rectangle>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Foreground="White" Text="Loading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,65,0,0"></TextBlock>
</Container>
```

BTW, this should look something like this:

```
 ---------------
|   ---------   |
|  | Loading |  |
|   ---------   |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
 ---------------
```

Thank you,

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not making much sense but are you looking for a [UserControl](http://www.insidercoding.com/post/2008/07/14/Tutorial-Creating-a-User-Control-in-Silverlight-20.aspx)?

(The link refers to Silverlight 2.0 but it is still valid)

If you want to style the controls with a single template you'll need a [Custom Control](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Silverlight-Custom-Control-The-Basics.aspx) (inherit from Control)